# Getting "?" question mark instead of special symbols when debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm getting "?" When debugging in Visual Studio instead of symbols such as ■, ♥ ...etc. I tried different solutions but nothing worked for me.

I have to use these symbols in my project.

it should looks like this:

[image: it should looks like this:]

but instead, I get:

[image: but instead, I get:]

I also tried to print them out as: `printf("■, ♥\n");` just to make sure that the problem isn't in my project but I got the same "?" question mark.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some source code which is responsible for displaying the characters. Using ASCII codes for displaying required characters can help you.

Comment: Seems like the font the console window is using is missing glyphs for those characters.  Can you change the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you to display the required character

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
         printf("%c\n", i);
    }
}
```

Here is the output on Console.

[image: Code output]
I have shown only the first seven characters in the loop, but can use more just by replacing 6 with the number that you want. When you get your symbol, you can simply use the ASCII Code to display the symbol. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Abdulelah you're using a console font that displays box instead of the heart etc. You could change your console font, this is nothing to do with C

Comment: @M.M I have just changed the console font and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: @vivek Thanks. So I can't print them out as "printf("■, ♥\n");".. right?